# Highlighting a specific area of a grid containing <br> and reformatting the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that looks like this

```
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586<br>17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042<br>2421902671055626321111109370544217506941658960408<br>07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188<br>
```

It's really a grid that looks like this without the newlines (just has`<br>`, no actual newlines (\n))

```
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586<br>
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042<br>
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408<br>
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188<br>
```

I want to bold a certain section of this grid that can change every time, for this example lets say I want to bold 8617. (This number could be longer and stretch multiple lines, my actual grid is much larger)

I want it to appear like this:

164271714799244429282308634656748139191231628245**86**
**17**866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188

I tried using this (maxStr is the string of numbers I want to replace)

```
gridString.replace(maxStr, "<strong>" + maxStr + "</strong>")
```

But that won't work because the string has `<br>` in it, so the string I actually have to replace is `86<br>17`

My question is: how can I replace a certain portion of numbers that stretch across multiple lines with their bold version while keeping the `<br>` where I need it.

**JSFiddle illustrating my problem:** https://jsfiddle.net/5d21c2r3/

Side note: I tried a solution where I removed all `<br>` from my grid, then replaced the text, then re-added `<br>` every 50 characters, but that didn't work either because the `<strong>` and `</strong>` end up adding a lot of characters.

Comment: Where is the data at the time when you want to do the replace? Is it already in the DOM? Is it a string in your app? Somewhere else?

Comment: It's a string in a variable, you can look in the jsfiddle if you want to see exactly how the code looks

Comment: I'd probably just write a quick parser that receives the digits to be located and manually searches through the text one at a time. That way it can automatically look past any `<br>` that it may find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a regex that allows optional `<br>` between any number:

```
var toReplace = "8617";

var regex = new RegExp("(" + toReplace.split("").join("(?:<br>)?") + ")")

document.write(gridString.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>"))
```

See [updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5d21c2r3/3/).

### Explanation

The regex produced is `/(8(?:<br>)?6(?:<br>)?1(?:<br>)?7)/`. `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. `?` after it means that it's optional — it can appear zero or one times. The `(` at the beginning and `)` at the end is a capturing group — it allows you to use the matched substring later as `$1`.